# Couldn't find .env file in node.js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm new to node.js. I have a node.js with react front end application. I'm saving environment variables in .env file which is under root folder. I added this .env file in root folder so that i can use these variable in client and server. But, When i run npm start, i get below error. Somehow, node is searching for .env file in server folder.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\my-app\server\.env'
at Object.openSync (fs.js:440:3)
at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:342:35)
at Object.config (C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\my-app\server\node_modules\dotenv\lib\main.js:96:29)      
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\my-app\server\server.js:2:26)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
errno: -4058,
syscall: 'open',
code: 'ENOENT',
path: 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\source\\repos\\my-app\\server\\.env'
}
```

Comment: add your folder structure

Comment: Please share your package.json of node project

Comment: So, to be clear, you added the .env file in the C:\\ directory? Standard practice would be to put environment variables in your project folder where you run "npm start" from. You may be able to reconfigure npm to recognize a different environment variable location, but the better solution is to put the environment variables in the project root.

Comment: Since you are new to node js, there might be a chance of missing basic usage of environmental variables. Please go through this blog completely [Node.js Everywhere with Environment Variables!](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786)

Comment: @Brightstar I have added the .env file in project root folder. Same as .gitignore file..

Comment: @Sachin1729 I have created .env file by following the same article. The solution is working if i move the .env file to server folder. But somehow it's not working if i move it to root folder.

Comment: @ravi1122 Can you please provide project structure and the code for, how you are importing.

Comment: @ravi1122 You may want to clarify: What is the difference between "root" and "server" and "project".  Normally the project's root folder IS the folder where your server's primary JS file is.